# How can my clickonce application request permission to edit registry and host file?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

So the problem here is that I'm using ClickOnce to create an internal application that co-workers can install once and I can push updates by publishing. The problem is that ClickOnce doesn't jive with my need for administrator privileges; it won't publish if I have that requirement declared in the app.manifest. The reason that I have that in there is that I need to be able to edit the host file which is in system32/drivers/etc. Most other threads I've read say that the most I can do is run `asInvoker` so that the app can inherit all of the permissions that I have as a principal user on the domain, but I found this to be a bit inaccurate. You see, my user has permissions to edit the host file, but my principal does not possess the administrator role. So my question is this...

How can my ClickOnce app request/gain permission to edit the host file? As an aside -- the applicaiton will also be doing some minor registry editing. Alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: If your app need administration elevation, ClickOnce is not your tool. The whole idea behind ClickOnce is just that, installation without administrative rights to ease deployment.

Comment: But surely, there is a way to request permission programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

As jvanrhyn alludes, the [official policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228996.aspx) is that ClickOnce applications cannot request administrative elevation if User Account Control (UAC) is enabled (as it is by default on Vista and later). Like you've discovered, if the manifest file sets the `requestedExecutionLevel` attribute to `requireAdministrator`, the application will fail to install and run.

This is a security precaution. The whole purpose of UAC is to minimize the risk of applications making unauthorized changes to system settings, which could compromise system integrity. The whole point of ClickOnce is to make deployment of applications fast and easy. Clearly these are two contradictory goals.

Again, the official stance is that if your applications requires administrative privileges, you should be deploying it using Windows Installer or some similar utility.

However, since as far as I understand your question you only need to have administrative privileges on first install, there might be a workaround where you can continue to use ClickOnce for deployment. You would keep the application's `requestedExecutionLevel` at `asInvoker` so that it would run under normal circumstances with standard (unelevated) privileges and would work with ClickOnce. But you would also have a secondary application that *did* require elevation. Your primary application would then launch this secondary application on demand (e.g., on first run), causing the secondary application's privilege demands to kick in, and thus prompt the user for elevation. That second application would run elevated, make the changes that it needed to make, and then quit. The primary application would continue to run un-elevated, and could be launched thereafter without requiring administrative privileges.

This is keeping with the spirit of the security precautions, since it minimizes the need for applications to run with administrative privileges. You can include the secondary "helper" application as a delivered resource in the ClickOnce application, and it can then be launched from the ClickOnce private storage area.